# How to determine a in r - in a function of relations

Tags: relations

I'm pretty stuck on the following question

$f$ on $\mathbb{R}$ given by $xfy\Leftrightarrow (y(2x-3)-3x=y(x^2-2x)-5x^3)$ is a function.

Let $g$ be the restriction of $f$ to $\mathbb{Z}^+$, implying $g(n) = f(n),\,n \in\mathbb{Z}^+$

Determine $a\in R\,$, so $g\in \Theta(n^a)$

Comment: Have you expressed $f(x)$ (by expressing $y$ in terms of $x$'s)?

Comment: In your last statement: "Determine $a \in R$...do you mean $a \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @Berci: Could u eloborate it?
amWhy Yes :)

Comment: y=(-5x^3+5x)/(-x^2+4x-3) is that what u mean :)?

Comment: If the question is solved, you indicate that by accepting an answer, not by changing the title to include the word solved.

Comment: Noticed - thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's express $y=f(x)$:
$$(x^2-2x-2x+3)y=5x^3-3x \implies y =\frac{5x^3-3x}{x^2-4x+3} $$
So, $a=3-2=1$ by the leading exponents.

**Update:** Formally, you have to prove that there are constants $A,B>0$ such that
$An\le f(n)\le Bn\ $ (for $n\ge n_0$).

Comment: Sadly there isnt no further explanation for it.
So i simply have to look on the exponents, sounds kinda to simply but then again its only 1/5 of the solution

Comment: Ok. So, find 'Big Theta' in the following page, and use the definition given there: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation